# Turning objects filtered from managedObjectContext into an NSArray

Tags: swift, core-data, nsarray, nsmanagedobject, ios8.1

I'm relatively new to iOS and I find myself "thrown to the wolves" on a Core Data assignment. I'm trying to create an array of `Note` objects using a `NSPredicate` to search a `managedObjectContext`. It's not working, but I think I'm close to the "finish line". Here's what I've got:

I have a `managedObjectContext` instantiated and there are `Note` objects in it.

I have a variable I created called `filteredNotes` at the top of the class that's instantiated empty (at least I think so).

```
var filteredNotes: [Note] = []
```

Further down, I have a function that I want to "fill up" the filteredNote array with note objects that match a predicate. Here's how I'm trying to do it:

```
    let resultPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "noteTitle contains[c] %@", searchBar.text)

    filteredNotes = (managedObjectContext as! NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(resultPredicate)
```

The compiler has this to say about it:

1. `Cast from 'NSManagedObjectContext?' to unrelated type 'NSArray' always fails`
2. `Cannot assign a value of type '[AnyObject]' to a value of type '[Note]'`

I see a lot of examples of vanilla `NSArrays` (not `managedObjectContexts`) doing this and I'm stumped why I can't do it w/ a `managedObjectContext` that's filled with `Note` objects.

Here's what my Note: NSManagedObject looks like:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class Note: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var dateCreated: NSDate
    @NSManaged var dateEdited: NSDate
    @NSManaged var noteTitle: String
    @NSManaged var noteBody: String

}
```

Any suggestions on how to create the `filteredNote` array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The managed object context has nothing to do with an array. It cannot be "filled" with objects. It is simply an abstract class that gives you access to your data.

The way you get objects from your Core Data store is as follows: make a fetch request, optionally add filter and/or sorting to the request, fetch the objects.

```
let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"Note")
let result = managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(request error:nil) as [Note]
```

You can now either filter this array (with `filteredArrayUsingPredicate` after casting to NSArray) or you can add your predicate to the original fetch request (which should even be more efficient).

Comment: `let result = ...` generates this compiler error: `Cannot invoke 'executeFetchRequest' with an argument list of type '(NSFetchRequest)'`

Comment: Sure, I forgot the error parameter - you could have figured this out yourself simply via autocompletion ;-).

Comment: Thank you! I'm a month into this, so I greatly appreciate your insight.

Comment: My instructor sent me back to the drawing board. He wanted something that uses CoreData from start-to-finish without arrays. I'm still working on it, but I've got  pretty good start. Here's another way if anyone cares: 
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28708865/swift-uisearchcontroller-wired-up-in-core-data-project-app-runs-but-search-not](Core Data from start to finish)

Comment: I described in my last sentence how to do that. Apple recommends in-memory filtering in some cases. Your instructor should read up on best practices.